# Make Final Android Studio

Tags: java, android, final

Im following a video online but im stuck with this where i cannot make the variable final. This code is being done in android studio.

> error: cannot find symbol variable i

The error can be found on the last 5 line.

```
intent.putExtra(Common.KEY_TIME_SLOT, i);
```

The only option i have is:

- Create local variable
- Create field
- Create Parameter
- Rename Reference

Heres the whole code:

```
@Override

    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.txt_time_slot.setText(new StringBuilder(Common.convertTimeSlotToString(position)).toString());
        if(timeSlotList.size()==0)//if all is available, show list
        {
            holder.card_time_slot.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
            holder.txt_time_slot_description.setText("Available");
            holder.txt_time_slot_description.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
            holder.txt_time_slot.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
        }
        else //if fully booked
        {
            for(TimeSlot slotValue:timeSlotList)
            {
                //loop all time slot from sever and set different color
                int slot = Integer.parseInt(slotValue.getSlot().toString());
                if(slot==position) // if slot == position
                {
                    holder.card_time_slot.setTag(Common.DISABLE_TAG);
                    holder.card_time_slot.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.darker_gray));
                    holder.txt_time_slot_description.setText("BOOKED");
                    holder.txt_time_slot_description.setTextColor(context.getResources()
                            .getColor(android.R.color.white));
                    holder.txt_time_slot.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));

                }
            }
        }

        //add available time slot
        if (!cardViewList.contains(holder.card_time_slot))
            cardViewList.add(holder.card_time_slot);
        //check if slot is available
        holder.setiRecyclerItemSelectedListener(new IRecyclerItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelectedListener(View view, int pos) {
                //loop all slots
                for(CardView cardView:cardViewList)
                {
                    if (cardView.getTag() == null)
                        cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getResources()
                                .getColor(android.R.color.white));
                }
                //selected slot will change color
                holder.card_time_slot.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getResources()
                .getColor(android.R.color.holo_orange_dark));

                //once selected, send signal to next button
                Intent intent = new Intent(Common.KEY_ENABLE_BUTTON_NEXT);
                intent.putExtra(Common.KEY_TIME_SLOT, i); // error. in the video it shows that i can make "i" final but on my end it does not show that option.
                intent.putExtra(Common.KEY_STEP,3); //going step 3
                localBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(intent);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Click on "Create Field". Then make it final yourself.

Comment: Typo: no variable with that name

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't that it isn't final (which you can make a variable final by typing the word final before it).  The problem is that it doesn't exist at all.  You don't have a variable named i anywhere.

i was probably supposed to be pos, the item which was actually selected.

Comment: thanks for this. it was the param pos. sorted out by changing i to pos.

Answer (score 0):

The error says it "cannot find symbol variable i", you have to create the variable first, and to make it final do: `final int i = 0;`